# Zigfu + unity3d OSX

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, zigfu

Has anyone managed to upgrade the Unity package from Zigfu to work with current version of unity?
I've used the particle updaters etc.
But sample scenes show warnings like this:

`The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'ZigFu') is missing!`

No idea how to update the scripts. I'm not getting any other errors just warnings.